# Sinon Spy not working with Javascript call or apply

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I'm trying to use `sinon.spy` to check if the `play` function is being called for a component. The problem is that the spy counter is not updating, even though I've confirmed that my component's function is indeed being called.

I've tracked it down to the use of Javascript's `call` function:

```
handleDone: function(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.components.length; i++) {
    if (this.components[i].element === e.target) {
      if (this.components[i].hasOwnProperty("play")) {
        // This won't trigger the spy.
        this.components[i]["play"].call(this.components[i].element);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

A similar thing happens when swapping `call` for `apply`.

[UPDATED]
Here is the relevant test:

```
var page = document.getElementById("page"),
  demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
  playSpy;

suiteSetup(function() {
  playSpy = sinon.spy(demo, "play");
});

suiteTeardown(function() {
  demo.play.restore();
});

suite("done", function() {
  test("rise-component-done fired from element with play property", function() {
    assert(playSpy.notCalled);  //true
    demo.sendDone();
    assert(playSpy.calledOnce); //false
  });
});
```

And the `play` and `sendDone` functions in the `demo` component:

```
play: function() {
  console.log("play");
},

sendDone: function() {
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("rise-component-done", { "bubbles": true }));
}
```

The `page` component is registered to listen for this event:

```
this.addEventListener("rise-component-done", this.handleDone);
```

Anyone know of a workaround?

Thx.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you are doing the spy of the play function? Maybe the entire test to see if it might come from there.

Comment: I've done a quick test using `call` and it seems to work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNOwvB?editors=101

Comment: I've updated with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem wasn't actually related to the `call` method at all as Ben illustrated. After much tinkering, I realized I had to change this line:

```
playSpy = sinon.spy(demo, "play");
```

to this:

```
playSpy = sinon.spy(page.components[0], "play");
```

Now my tests pass. Hooray! I just wish it hadn't taken me the better part of a day to debug.