# sinon spy not wrapping method in asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

It appears that `sinon.spy(object, method)` is not wrapping my object#method as expected.

*(I have an uneasy feeling that I'm seeing the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041079/sinon-spy-is-not-called-if-the-spied-method-is-called-indirectly) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370799/sinon-spy-not-working-with-javascript-call-or-apply), but I don't see why this should be.  I've instantiated my object before calling `sinon.spy(...)`, and AFAIK I'm not using any cached objects.)*

Here's the complete test file:

```
var 
AmbitParser = require('../lib/parsers/ambit-parser'),
expect = require('chai').expect,
sinon = require('sinon');

describe('AmbitParser', function() {
    var ambit_parser = new AmbitParser();

    describe('#extractLineItems()', function() {

        it('calls extractLineItems once', function(done) {
            var spy = sinon.spy(ambit_parser, 'extractLineItems');

            ambit_parser.parseBills(function gotBills(err, bills) {
                expect(ambit_parser.extractLineItems.callCount).to.equal(1); // => expected undefined to equal 1
                expect(spy.callCount).to.equal(1);                           // => expected 0 to equal 1
                done();
            });

            ambit_parser.extractLineItems.restore();
        });                     // calls extractLineItems once
    });                         // #extractLineItems
});                             // AmbitParser
```

The call to `expect(ambit_parser.extractLineItems.callCount).to.equal(1);` results in 'expected undefined to equal 1' and if I change that to `expect(spy.callCount).to.equal(1);`, I get 'expected 0 to equal 1'.

Together, this makes me think that the call to `sinon.spy(...)` is not wrapping the ambit_parser.extractLineItems method as expected, but I can't see why this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the placement of the call to `restore()`: it should not be in the body of the test function.  Instead, put it in an `after()` block.

What's happening is that the restore() method is getting called immediately after the test is started, so by the time the callback is executed, the spied upon method has been restored, so sinon will report that the method has never been called.

The following modifications to the original code will work as expected:

```
describe('AmbitParser', function() {
    var ambit_parser = new AmbitParser();

    describe('#extractLineItems()', function() {

        before(function() {
            sinon.spy(ambit_parser, 'extractLineItems');
        });
        after(function() {
            ambit_parser.extractLineItems.restore();
        });

        it('calls extractLineItems once', function(done) {
            ambit_parser.parseBills(function gotBills(err, bills) {
                expect(ambit_parser.extractLineItems.callCount).to.equal(1);
                done();
            });
        });                     // calls extractLineItems once
    });                         // #extractLineItems
});                             // AmbitParser
```

Moral of the story: make sure you call `reset()` only after any callbacks have completed.